# How do I enable the Sidebar in Finder?

Tags: sidebar

I know its a simple menu item somewhere, but I can't find it anywhere! I really want the sidebar to always show when I open a new Finder window. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?  Odd.

Comment: @harv Because it didn't show any research effort.

Comment: @Lari I did a google search before posting, but I didn't find the answer quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select Finder and click **View** → **Show Sidebar** or press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

A tip when it comes to menus: if you go to the Help menu and search for what you want. It will highlight the result in the menu if you hover over it.

Comment: Note however that you need to show the toolbar first (View->Show Toolbar), before the Show Sidebar option becomes available.

Comment: What am I to do if `Show Sidebar` is greyed out? http://puu.sh/kkWdS.png